# Is-a relationships in Generics

Tags: c#, generics

Suppose we have generic classes `G1<T>` and `G2<T>: G1<T>`. And classes `C1` and `C2: C1`.

Of the following which is not true?:

```
G2<C1> is-a G1<C1>,
G1<C2> is-a G1<C1>,
G2<C2> is-a G1<C1>
```

Aside from these is there any case that would surprise intuition?

Comment: Neither the 2nd nor the 3rd are true.

Comment: The `is` operator exists in C#, you can verify your claims yourself.

Comment: What you should be doing is [imposing generic constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) to ensure that this actually happens in your backend. Otherwise I have no idea what you are talking about here

Comment: did you test it? https://dotnetfiddle.net/mK3Dmh Notice: i have added an example for contravariant https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/in-generic-modifier

Comment: Intuition comes alongside experience. So its a personal things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to check:

```cs
Console.WriteLine(new G2<C1>() is G1<C1>); // True
Console.WriteLine(new G1<C2>() is G1<C1>); // False
Console.WriteLine(new G2<C2>() is G1<C1>); // False

class C1{}
class C2:C1{}
class G1<T>{}
class G2<T>:G1<T>{}
```

[Demo](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgNAJiA1AHwAICYCMBYAUKzATgAooBTAdwAIBxdAHgGFMA+YgSioEsBnWzJq3YBuKgHoxVACqQyeAiXLUaAxujade/QSxHjJAMQCGAGx5z8RUpVoM1G7nxU69EqsbMX56KswDeAL7evugg/kH4Ps5SLIHBdPQxINGxAUA===)

The last two in general case are quite easy to explain. Imagine `G1` being:

```cs
class G1<T>
{
    public T Data { get; set; }
}
```

Then if `new G1<C2>() is G1<C1>` would be true then the next would be possible -
`((G1<C1>)new G1<C2>()).Data = new C1();` which obviously breaks type safety.

Something can be done with [variance support in generic interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/variance-in-generic-interfaces), but it is limited to interfaces.